# How to change position of a carousel depending on screen size?

Tags: bootstrap-4

how to Change the position of a carousel depending on screen size?

```
#carousel-1 {
  width: 1024;
  height: 439;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

I have block containing 1 row 2 column.in the left column, I have heading and text and in the right column, I have the carousel.
expected results:
for the mobile screen, I want the carousel to come below heading and text.
actual results:
carousel still remain on the right side of the screen.

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 0):

You can use MeidaQuery for this purpose. Your desirable screen work properly as u want.

Comment: for reference system https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp